# Python pandas to extract only desired column and desired values from the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use `pandas` to parse my CSV file, where my CSV file has multiple columns but I need to pick only certain ones. From my CSV file I'm looking to grab `'Platform ID'` ,  that may startswith `CS-Unix*` next one is `'Target system address'` where it contains Sever names which could be anything so I need whole value to be printed out another and the last column is `'Failure reason'` which again a symptom and could be anything so need that printed.

I mentioned `CS-Unix-*` , because it could be anything after `CS-Unix-`
However, in another field, I opted `*` to print the value as Server name could again be different.

My Data Format will be ..

```
Platform ID               Target system address       Failure reason
CS-Unix-RootAccounts-SSH  Serer1                       xyz
```

Below what I'm trying but not working.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)

data = pd.read_csv('/home/karn/plura/Test/Python_Pnada/Cyber_July.csv', usecols=['Platform ID', 'Target system address', 'Failure reason'])
#data.drop(data.index[0], inplace=True)
hostnames = data[(data['Platform ID']=='CDS-Unix-*') | (data['Target system address'] == '*' )]['Failure reason']
print(hostnames)
```

Please guide to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide failure reasons for all the rows with Platform IDs of the form `CS-Unix-*`.

`hostnames = data[data['Platform ID'].str.startswith("CS-Unix-")][['Target system address','Failure reason']]`

[startswith()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) returns a boolean indicating whether the elements start with the string passes as a parameter to it.

Comment: gaganso, let me try this.

Comment: gaganso,  I need `Failure reason` and `Target system address` for all the rows with Platform IDs of the form CS-Unix-*, in that case what would be the `hostnames`.

Comment: @pygo, please see the updated answer. That is the syntax to select a subset of columns from the dataframe.